# Condition or Rule when Importing Excel data to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, import-from-excel

At **line 4** of my code, how or is it possible to have a condition in there?

For example:

Dim expr As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] ***WHERE excelColumn1 <> NULL***"

**I have tried it, but it gives an Error: No value given for one or more required parameters.**

```
    Dim ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\z.fontanilla\Documents\etl2.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes""")
    ExcelConnection.Open()

    Dim expr As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
    Dim objCmdSelect As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(expr, ExcelConnection)

    Dim objDR As OleDbDataReader

    Dim SQLconn As New SqlConnection()
    Dim ConnString As String = "Data Source=cyayay\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=reportingDB;Integrated Security=True"
    SQLconn.ConnectionString = ConnString
    SQLconn.Open()


    Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(SQLconn)
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tFalse"

        Try
            objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)
            objDR.Close()
            SQLconn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Using
    ExcelConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Have you tried your query? Which error you have got?

Comment: I got this Error: No value given for one or more required parameters.